# Compile GitHub Project to be used in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, github

How can I take a github project, that I have forked and edited, and the compile it so that is can be used like this

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.name:project:1.0'
```

How can I turn a fork into something that can be used like this?

Thanks

Comment: you need to configure gradle to upload the artifact to maven repository. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html

Comment: Otherwise, the another way is have a local copy and import as module

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan I am still confused about how to turn a github project into some I can compile in my grade? could you provide a bit more info on how to do this?

Comment: You mean locally or creating an artifact?

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan creating an artifact

Comment: I think that the link above and this one can help you: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html

Comment: @DeividiCavarzan right, but I still dont see how I go from a github url like this one just as example `https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader.git` I can fork it and add it to my page and edit it, and then from that fork use it so I can compile it like this ` compile 'com.github.name:project:1.0'` without adding it locally

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97782/discussion-between-deividi-cavarzan-and-iqueqiorio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install some lib locally, you need to declare the project in gradle:

In `settings.gradle` file, change the configuration to:

```
include ':app', ':your-lib'
project(':your-lib').projectDir = new File('Path/To/The/Lib/library')
```

After this include in your build.gradle the dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":your-lib")
}
```

This will import in you IDE the module of the library, and compiles to your APK.